# zend framework: class not found

Tags: zend-framework, classnotfound

i have problem in zend framework basic application that class is not found. please help

i have basic structure and added model/tables directory.  After my login page is displayed when i submit it then following error occurs

**Fatal error**: Class 'Application_models_tables_User' not found in E:\zendu\Apache2\htdocs\login\application\controllers\AuthController.php on line 18

Authcontroller.php

```
class AuthController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function loginAction()
{
    $data = new Application_models_tables_User();

}
```

models/tables/User.php

```
class Application_models_tables_User extends Zend_Db_Table
{
protected $_name = 'users';
}
```

in application.ini

```
appnamespace = "Application"
```

i am using zend studio so basic structure is automaticaly created. so i have not to set include path of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read through [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module) :

The module resource autoloader sets the folder 'models' to the namespace `Model`.

I would change your class name to `Application_Model_Table_User`, and change your 'model/tables' folder to `models/Table`